# Regex to find character only if it occurs 4 times

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck on making this Regex. I tried using look-ahead and look-behind together, but I couldn't use the capture group in the look-behind. I need to extract characters from a string ONLY if it occurs 4 times.

If I have these strings

- 3346AAAA44
- 3973BBBBBB44
- 9755BBBBBBAAAA44

The first one will match because it has 4 A's in a row. 
The second one will NOT match because it has 6 B's in a row.
The third one will match because it still has 4 A's. What makes it even more frustrating, is that it can be any char from A to Z occuring 4 times.

Positioning does not matter.

EDIT: My attempt at the regex, doesn't work.

```
(([A-Z])\2\2\2)(?<!\2*)(?!\2*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If lookbehind is allowed, after capturing the character, negative lookbehind for `\1.` (because if that matches, the start of the match is preceded by the same character as the captured first character). Then backreference the group 3 times, and negative lookahead for the `\1`:

```js
`3346AAAA44
3973BBBBBB44
9755BBBBBBAAAA44`
.split('\n')
.forEach((str) => {
  console.log(str.match(/([a-z])(?<!\1.)\1{3}(?!\1)/i));
});
```

- `([a-z])` - Capture a character
- `(?<!\1.)` Negative lookbehind: check that the position at the 1st index of the captured group is not preceded by 2 of the same characters
- `\1{3}` - Match the same character that was captured 3 more times
- `(?!\1)` - After the 4th match, make sure it's not followed by the same character

Comment: `([a-z])(?<!\1{2})\1{3}(?!\1)` simplifies it a bit more

Comment: Just to mention, it does not match eg `AAAA`, `AAAAB`

Answer (score 2):

Another version without lookbehind (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pDFDTB/5)). The captured sequence of 4 equal characters will be rendered in **Group 2**.

```
(?:^|(?:(?=(\w)(?!\1))).)(([A-Z])\3{3})(?:(?!\3)|$)
```

- `(?:^|(?:(?=(\w)(?!\1))).)` - ensure it's the beginning of the string. Otherwise, the 2nd char must be different from the 1st one - if yes, skip the 1st char.
- `(([A-Z])\3{3})` Capture 4 repeated `[A-Z]` chars
- `(?:(?!\3)|$)` - ensure the first char after those 4 is different. Or it's the end of the string

As it was suggested by bobble-bubble in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59174394/regex-to-find-character-only-if-it-occurs-4-times/59175676#comment104574948_59175676) - the expression above can be simplified to ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/pDFDTB/7)):

```
(?:^|(\w)(?!\1))(([A-Z])\3{3})(?!\3)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to the failing case and for ideas how to fix. I've slightly restructured the regex, so it should handle the `AAAAA` case properly now.

Comment: Smart update. Looks like really nice! I already upvoted :) I wonder if it still would work [a bit shorter like this](https://regex101.com/r/pDFDTB/7). However, hats off :)

Comment: Your shortened version is very nice! Seems to work well with all scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Another variant could be capturing the first char in a **group 1**.

Assert that then the previous 2 chars on the left are not the same as group 1, match an additional 3 times group 1 which is a total of 4 the same chars.

Then assert what is on the right is not group 1.

```
([A-Z])(?<!\1\1)\1{3}(?!\1)
```

- `([A-Z])` Capture group 1, match a single char A-Z
- `(?<!\1\1)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not 2 times group 1
- `\1{3}` Match 3 times group 1
- `(?!\1)` Assert what is on the right is not group 1

For example

```js
let pattern = /([A-Z])(?<!\1\1)\1{3}(?!\1)/g;
[
  "3346AAAA44",
  "3973BBBBBB44",
  "9755BBBBBBAAAA44",
  "AAAA",
  "AAAAB",
  "BAAAAB"
].forEach(s =>
  console.log(s + " --> " + s.match(pattern))
);
```